# ReactJS: How to have multiple SPA's on the same website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, single-page-application

I'm creating an Airbnb clone.

I noticed if I made the whole website one SPA then my nested routes would be a huge mess. I wanted to make each tab it's own SPA, but ran into errors when trying to create multiple SPAs.

What I did was create an App component and then rendered it to the Index.html, that worked!

But when I created a BecomeAHost component, and tried to render it to BecomeAHost.html (a different page) I got an error:

```
bundle.js:886 Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...):
Target container is not a DOM element.
```

My main question is: How do I have multiple ReactJS single page applications on the same website so I don't have about 30 routes all nested together?

**Here is the Github repo: https://github.com/strangebnb/template**

Here is the 2nd component that I'm trying to render on a BecomeAHost.html

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Component} from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, DefaultRoute, IndexLink, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {RadioButton, RadioButtonGroup} from 'material-ui/RadioButton';
import ActionFavorite from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/favorite';
import ActionFavoriteBorder from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/favorite-border';

const styles = {
  block: {
    maxWidth: 250,
  },
  radioButton: {
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
};


const BecomeAHost = React.createClass ({
  render() {
    return(
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <First/>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
})

const First = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Become an Airbnb host</h1>
    <p>Start off by creating a listing page. Think of it as a profile page for your place.</p>
    <br></br>
    <p>Step 1</p>
    <h3>Start with the basics</h3>
    <h4>Beds, bathrooms, amenities, and more</h4>
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<BecomeAHost />, document.getElementById('host'));
```

Here is how I'm trying to render it on the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Template</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='host'>Loading...</div>
    <script src='./bundle/bundle.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think the error may be that my webpack is configured to only handle my main App (my main App on Index.html does work). Here is my webpack

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: "./src/App.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: "./public",
        filename: "/bundle/bundle.js"
    },
    devtools: "sourcemap",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel"
            },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders:  ["style", "css", "sass"],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Multiple SPA in one page? that's no single page :P, besides we can't help you without code

Comment: I mean how do I have a SPA on each page! Sorry about lack of code. I just edited post to include github repo.

Comment: It's a bit hard considering it's on 4 different pages. Let me attempt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because both of your pages loads the same bundle, it will never find both the `app` **and** the `host` DOM elements to render correctly. Try using webpack's [multiple entry points](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html) and then require them separately in each `.html`:

```
{
    entry: {
        a: "./a",
        b: "./b",
        c: ["./c", "./d"]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].entry.js"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching for 3-4 hours now. Googling, "ReactJS how to have multiple SPA's on a website" did not turn anything useful.

Comment: Because it's not a SPA if there is multiple pages :P

Comment: Dammit, I'm so newb to web dev that I don't even know how to google my problem properly. Thank you again, Martriay. I upvoted your answer, but since I don't have rep, it doesn't show publicly.